# Python Error Handling when using requests

Tags: python, error-handling, python-requests

I wrote the script below to be able to connect to a remote server and get some data from the XML file. I added some error handling to be able to skip issues with some devices. For some reason whenever the script gets a 401 message back, it breaks the whole loop and I get the message "Could not properly read the csv file". I tried other ways of handling the exception and it would fail at other points. Any info on how to properly deal with this?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, re, csv, xmltodict
import requests, logging
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

def version(ip, username, password):
    baseUrl = "https://" + ip
    session = requests.Session()
    session.verify = False
    session.timeout = 45

    print "Connecting to " + ip
    try:
        r = session.get(baseUrl + '/getxml?location=/Status', auth=(username, password))
        r.raise_for_status()
    except Exception as error:
        print err

    doc = xmltodict.parse(r.text)

    version  = str(doc['Status']['@version'])

def main():
    try:
        with open('list.csv', 'r') as file:
            reader = csv.DictReader(file)
            for row in reader:
                version(row['ip'], row['Username'], row['Password'])
    except Exception as error:
        print ValueError("Could not properly read the csv file \r")
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `doc` and `version` variables in `def version` are outside the `try: catch:` so when `r` is `None` due to exception, the next 2 operations also fail, raising some uncaught exception. Which surfaces in `main`. Can you try including `doc` and `version` within the `try: catch:` and see if it works.

**A related suggestion**: catch specific exceptions as this helps know more about why your code crashed. ex. `Response.raise_for_status()` raises `requests.exceptions.HTTPError`. Catch that, raise all other exceptions. xml might raise something else, catch that, instead of catching ALL.

Comment: I thought I had tried that, but I just redid it and it worked perfectly. 401 handling, no connection handling! thanks!